# Taurus error when try to check response code

Tags: blazemeter, taurus

I am trying to assert the response for a HTTP GET

```
execution:
- executor: selenium
  scenario: dashboard
  iterations: 1

reporting:
- module: final-stats
  dump-xml: results/test.xml
  dump-csv: results/test2.csv
- module: junit-xml
  filename: results/testfinal.xml
  data-source: pass-fail  


modules:
  console:
    disable: true

scenarios:
  dashboard: 
    browser: Chrome
    timeout: 60s
    default-address: https://${URL}
    requests:
    - label: ignore
      url: https://${URL}
      actions:
      - waitByXPath(/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/input[4]): Visible
      - keysByXPath(/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/input[4]): ${USERNAME}
      - keysByXPath(/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/input[5]): ${PASSWORD}
      - clickByXPath(/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div[4]/button)

    - url: /Sites/testsite/api/level1/status/auth-service-health-check 
      method: GET  
      assert:
       - contains:
          - 200
      subject: status-code
```

Error i am getting is **"TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern"**

Please can any one help with this
All what i need to check is whether the reponse status is 200 for url: /Sites/testsite/api/level1/status/auth-service-health-check

issue is on here exactly

```
- contains:
    - 200
  subject: status-code
```

if i add like this error disappeared but then it checking the response body not status code

```
- contains:
    - '200'
  subject: status-code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the `subject` to `http-code`?:

```
subject: http-code
```

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion to check http-code instead of status-code is correct.  To expand on that, check out the explanation here:
https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#HTTP-Requests

Scroll down a bit and there's a discussion of how exactly assertions work in Taurus, with some examples.  Of particular note is this part:

> Possible subjects are:
>       body
>       headers
>       http-code